# Rolling Mean/standard deviation with conditions

Tags: r, data.table, moving-average

I have a bit of a question about computing the Rolling Mean/standard deviation based on conditions. To be honest it is more of a syntax question, but since I think it is slowing down my code quite a bit I thought I should ask it here to find out what's going on. I have some finance data with columns such as `Stock Name`, `Midquotes` etc. and I would like to compute the rolling mean and rolling standard deviation based on the stock.

Right now I wish to compute the volatility of each stock, and this is done by taking the rolling standard deviation of the previous 20 midquotes. To this end, after searching through the stackoverflow forums, I found a line using the `data.table` package as follows:

```
DT[, volatility:=( roll_sd(DT$Midquotes, 20, fill=0, align = "right") ), by = Stock]
```

Where `DT` is the `data.table` which contains all my data.

Now, this is quite computationally slow, especially when I compare it to a typical rolling standard deviation calculation without any conditions as given here:

```
DT$volatility <- roll_sd(DT$Midquotes, 20, fill=0, align = "right")
```

But when I try to do something similar with the rolling standard deviation with a condition, R will not let me do this:

```
DT$volatility <- DT[, ( roll_sd(DT$Midquotes, 20, fill=0, align = "right") ), by = Stock]
```

This line comes up with an error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10.9 Gb
```

So I was just wondering, why is this line: `DT[, volatility:=( roll_sd(DT$Midquotes, 20, fill=0, align = "right") ), by = Stock]` so slow? Is it perhaps making a copy of the entire `data.table` each time the rolling standard deviation is computed for each different stock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is your use of the `:=` function and that you use `DT` inside the square brackets. I assume your setup is something like:

```
> library(data.table)
> set.seed(83385668)
> DT <- data.table(
+   x     = rnorm(5 * 3), 
+   stock = c(sapply(letters[1:3], rep, times = 5)),
+   time  = c(replicate(3, 1:5)))
> DT
              x stock time
 1:  0.25073356     a    1
 2: -0.24408170     a    2
 3: -0.87475856     a    3
 4:  0.50843761     a    4
 5: -1.91331773     a    5
 6:  0.07850094     b    1
 7: -0.15922989     b    2
 8:  1.09806870     b    3
 9:  0.27995610     b    4
10:  0.45090842     b    5
11:  0.03400554     c    1
12: -0.34918734     c    2
13:  2.16602740     c    3
14: -0.04758261     c    4
15:  1.24869663     c    5
```

I am not sure where the `roll_sd` function is from. However, you can compute e.g. a rolling mean with the `zoo` library as follows:

```
> library(zoo)
> setkey(DT, stock, time) # make sure data is sorted by time
> DT[, rollmean := rollmean(x, k = 3, fill = 0, align = "right"), 
+    by = .(stock)]
> DT
              x stock time   rollmean
 1:  0.25073356     a    1  0.0000000
 2: -0.24408170     a    2  0.0000000
 3: -0.87475856     a    3 -0.2893689
 4:  0.50843761     a    4 -0.2034676
 5: -1.91331773     a    5 -0.7598796
 6:  0.07850094     b    1  0.0000000
 7: -0.15922989     b    2  0.0000000
 8:  1.09806870     b    3  0.3391132
 9:  0.27995610     b    4  0.4062650
10:  0.45090842     b    5  0.6096444
11:  0.03400554     c    1  0.0000000
12: -0.34918734     c    2  0.0000000
13:  2.16602740     c    3  0.6169485
14: -0.04758261     c    4  0.5897525
15:  1.24869663     c    5  1.1223805
```

or equivalently

```
> DT[, `:=`(rollmean = rollmean(x, k = 3, fill = 0, align = "right")), 
+    by = .(stock)]
> DT
              x stock time   rollmean
 1:  0.25073356     a    1  0.0000000
 2: -0.24408170     a    2  0.0000000
 3: -0.87475856     a    3 -0.2893689
 4:  0.50843761     a    4 -0.2034676
 5: -1.91331773     a    5 -0.7598796
 6:  0.07850094     b    1  0.0000000
 7: -0.15922989     b    2  0.0000000
 8:  1.09806870     b    3  0.3391132
 9:  0.27995610     b    4  0.4062650
10:  0.45090842     b    5  0.6096444
11:  0.03400554     c    1  0.0000000
12: -0.34918734     c    2  0.0000000
13:  2.16602740     c    3  0.6169485
14: -0.04758261     c    4  0.5897525
15:  1.24869663     c    5  1.1223805
```

Comment: Note that `rollmeanr` (with an r on the end) in zoo is like `rollmean` but defaults to right alignment for slightly more compact code.

Comment: Wow, that works extremely fast now and was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks heaps :)

Comment: Is there any way to define that the rolling is always along the `time` dimension? Is it sufficient, that the `time` column is ordered accordingly?

Comment: You need to sort the data before as `rollmean` assumes that data is sorted. See `help("rollmean")`. I am not entirely sure that I get your question.

Answer (score 2):

There now also is a rolling mean function within data.table itself, please see [github disscussion](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2778) for details. The implementation is really straightforward.

```
DT[, rollmean := data.table::frollmean(x, n = 3, fill = 0, align = "right"), 
by = .(stock)]
```

A quick benchmarking of the two, shows that the `data.table` version is a bit quicker (most of the time).

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(a = DT[, rollmean := data.table::frollmean(x, n = 3, fill = 0, align = "right"), 
                      by = .(stock)]
               , b = DT[, rollmean := rollmean(x, k = 3, fill = 0, align = "right"),
                            by = .(stock)]
, times = 100L

)

Unit: milliseconds
expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq     max neval cld
   a 1.5695 1.66605 2.329675 1.79340 2.1980 39.3750   100  a 
   b 2.6711 2.82105 3.660617 2.99725 4.3577 20.3178   100   b
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem calculating rolling standard in my data-processing process.So I viewed this site. And I think your problem is using DT$Midquotes not .SD$Midquotes. .SD is a data.table containing the Subset of x’s Data for each group. And roll_sd function is from package"RcppRoll".
You can try this way.

```
DT[, (sd = roll_sd(.SD$Midquotes, 20, fill=0, align = "right")), by = .(Stock)]
```

Comment: It's a good practice to explain your answer on SO, not just to post the code. Why don't you improve the answer by editing it?